# Creating parallax effect with Vuetify using an SVG file

Tags: vue.js, svg, parallax, vuetify.js

`vuetify` provides the `v-parallax` component to create a typical `parallax` effect, which creates a 3d effect that makes an image appear to scroll slower than the window:

```
<template>
  <v-parallax src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material.jpg"></v-parallax>
</template>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with `svg` files.

Does anybody know whether there is an easy way to create a `parallax` effect with `vuetify` or `vue`, but using an `svg` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it if you pass the svg data base64 encoded

`data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]` where `[data]` would be the data you get by passing it into an encoder like https://www.base64encode.org/

example:

```html
<v-parallax src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" height="200">
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea, but I need the xml tags to transform the image via e.g. anime.js